# Can't find the meaning of 「パー」

Tags: meaning

I have searched through a few dictionaries and through google but i can't seem to find an answer. from the fact that it's not found in any standard dictionary indicates it's an abbreviation but because of that i don't know the original word. so can't find it.

one sentence example:

> 「その辺は問題ないわ。私達神々の親切サポートによって、異世界に行く際にあなたの脳に負荷を掛けて、一瞬で習得できるわ。もちろん文字だって読めるよ？副作用として、運が悪いと**パー**になるかもだけれど。・・・だから、後は凄い能力か装備を選ぶだけね」

Example 2:

> もしかしたら**パー**になるかもという恐怖はあるが、自慢ではないが運の強さに関してだけは、子供の頃から自信がある。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be having trouble finding it because it's apparently listed as ぱあ in dictionaries. See definition #3 for the meaning of パー in your examples.

[From デジタル大辞泉 definition on Kotobank:](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%B1%E3%81%82-597837)

> ぱあ
>
> ［名・形動］
>
> １ じゃんけんで、5本の指をすべて開いた形。かみ。「ぐう、ちょき、ぱあ」
>
> ２ 持っていた金品がすっかりなくなること。それまで苦労したことが全くむだになること。また、そのさま。「台風で旅行の計画がぱあになる」
>
> ３ 間抜けなこと。また、そのさま。ばか。「あいつぱあなんじゃないか」

Comment: いや、この文脈ではExample 1 も Example 2 も、 #３の意味でしょう。脳に負荷をかける副作用で、クルクルパーになるかもしれない、という。。

Comment: あっ、そうなんですね。先、回答を編集しました。教えていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: Ah, i can see how it fits into all this now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do we know why the name of the "paper" move in RPS came to mean to lose everything or to have everything come to nothing?

Answer (score 5):

“パー” as popular slang means “idiocy.” For example, we say:

> - 僕たちの言うことが全く解らない。あいつはパーだ – He is really an idiot! He doesn’t understand what we are saying at all.
> - 彼はまたばかなことをした。ほんとにパーだな – He made the same mistake again. He is a damn idiot.

Therefore 「パーになる」 means “become an idiot, or imbecile."

So, the line, “副作用として、運が悪いとパーになるかもだけれど” can be interpreted as:

> “If you are unlucky, you may become an idiot as a side effect of the operation by imposing a heavy load to your brain.”

and, “もしかしたらパーになるかもという恐怖はあるが” as:

> “Though I have a fear that I may turn into an idiot, if it didn’t work.”

---

「パーになる」 also means “come to nothing,” and “end in a total failure.” We say:

> - 市のソニー組み立て工場誘致計画はパーになった – The City’s plan to solicit Sony’s assembly factory was busted.
> - 彼の会社は倒産して、あれほどあった資産もパーになった – His company went bankrupt. All assets that rose above have gone.

Comment: _“パー” as popular slang meaning “idiocy.”_ -- I wonder what that suggests about golf?  </oyaji>

Comment: "Par, par three, par four, par X " are  commonly used in golf in the same way as in English. But 〝パー - pah" in my examples are irrelevant to "par" being used when golfing. I don't know the origin of Japanese パー. Maybe it's from パー of グー、チョキ、パー in "Rock, scissors and paper" game. When you open the palm, it means empty - nothing is left. It's my guess.

Comment: 冗談：外れた！（´д｀）ご迷惑すみませんでした。「パー」＝「バカ」ならば、というところからの親父ギャグに過ぎませんでした。（＾＾）

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about the context, but from reading your example, most likely the direct translation would be "screwed up". It's not a formal word, rather used conversationally.